# Python Script in Crontab: rm: cannot remove, no such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a crontab running on Linux 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64. In it, I have
a python script that prints out certain files to delete, and then I pipe it to `xargs rm`.

for example, i would run the script `python delete_these.py` and it would print out the following:

```
/directory/to/delete1.txt
/directory/to/delete2.txt
/directory/to/delete3.txt
/directory/to/delete4.txt
```

and these would be deleted through `| xargs rm` run on the same command prompt. so

```
python delete_these.py | xargs rm
```

The script runs fine when run manually, however when it's run on cron, it returns an error in stdout retrieved from the mail when the job is run:

```
rm: cannot remove '/directory/to/delete1.txt': No such file or directory
```

here's what i input in crontab:

```
* * * * * ssh [confidential@stuff.com] python /location/where/my/python/script/is | xargs rm
```

i've done `chmod +x /path/to/python/script` and putting the full command (minus the stars, but including the `ssh`) works fine on the command line, but running it on cron returns the 'no such file or directory' error.

I am sure that these files exist, and they are not symblinks.

i've retried it with attaching the associated absolute directory for python (`usr/bin/`) but it still doesn't work.

i have no idea why the cron doesn't work. the current `PATH` on the crontab set by another user is a directory to `usr/bin/stuff` that is specific to that box. 
I thought it would be an issue with the `PATH` being different, but I don't think this is the case as I specify absolute directories within the command.

any ideas? i'm totally stumped on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're running the `python` command on one computer and the `rm` on another computer

you should probably quote the pipe (`|`) so it doesn't separate things

at a guess the crontab line should be:

```
* * * * * ssh [confidential@stuff.com] "python /location/where/my/python/script/is | xargs rm"
```

Comment: what would that look like? would it just be: 

`* * * * * ssh [confidential@stuff.com] python /location/where/my/python/script/is | "xargs rm"  ` ?

Comment: added an example, but you could just use `\|` or `"|"` if you're using a bourne shell

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!